# Objective C MFMailComposeViewController Cancel -> Cancel button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: rounded cancel button]  Please find the code and attached pic. That cancel button not working . If I click that button, that modal alone closing. It is not triggering "mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult" function..I am new to Objective c IOS. Please help me to get out of this issue. I searched in stack overflow. But I problem didn't solve

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *send;
- (IBAction)sendMail:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController 
MFMailComposeViewController* controller;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
 controller= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


 - (IBAction)sendMail:(id)sender {

[controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hello there." isHTML:NO];
if (controller)         [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

 }

 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError*)error;
 {
 NSLog(@"Coming here");
 if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
    NSLog(@"Mail It's away!");
 }
 if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
    NSLog(@"Mail Error!");
 }
 if(result == MFMailComposeResultCancelled){
    NSLog(@"Mail Error!");

 }
 if(result == MFMailComposeResultSaved){
    NSLog(@"Mail Saved!");

 }
 [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 return;
 }
 [![Screen shot][1]][1]@end
```

Comment: Any `NSLog` is printed?

Comment: And if you send it, is your delegate method called? Is your issue only with Cancel? I don't think so. You didn't set the delegate, so it's unlikely to be called. Add `@interface ViewController () MFMailComposerDelegate` and `[controller setDelegate:self];`.  Also, you should check `canSendMail` (it's not present in your code).

Comment: @Larme. .In viewDidLoad I am setting delegate...Can you please tell what is canSendMail?

Comment: No @ReinierMelian . If I click saveDraft,deleteDraft it s coming to "mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult" function. But if I click cancel button it is not coming..

Comment: Sorry, missed the line where you set the delegate, my bad.

Comment: @Larme It's ok. Can you please tell me about canSendMail method?

Comment: I had tested and its weird the only button not working is the cancel button, seems a bug to me

Comment: Yes @ReinierMelian ..Is there any method we want to overwrite ?

Comment: It's in the doc (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller?language=objc) And you error seems weird if other options triggers the delegate method correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man this cancel button does nothing at all other than dismissing action sheet. If you want to get rid of mail composer you have to press cancel at upper left corner which shows you an action sheet at the bottom with options Delete Draft, Save Draft and cancel. Delete draft and save draft will dismiss the mail composer and the delegate function will be called. Cancel button will actually dismiss action sheet in order to save the mail composer from dismissing in case if user accidentally clicked that cancel button at the top